# UIViewContainer with UITableVIewContainer subView, UITableViewContainer.View leaves gap at top

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UISegmentedControl that swaps out one of 3 UITableViewControllers depending up the pressed segment selected. Everything works great, except the UITableViewControllers do not fill the entire available screen, but leave a gap at the top  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that simply posting on Stack Overflow helps me find the answer myself!  From another question, I'm resizing the frame with `[myController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];` though I don't believe this should be required.